# Is it safe to upgrade to 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-10

Here's a little background of what I've been through:
I'm starting to learn to program by following theodinproject.com curricula. I'm currently stuck at the [OS Installation section](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-prerequisites) of the said course as a 64-bit hardware is needed to download VirtualBox and Xubuntu. As I'm searching for the answer to my problem, I came across to [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/) blog post that it is possible to upgrade your 32-bit OS to a 64-bit OS IF your computer and "hardware" is 64-bit capable.

I'm using Acer Aspire 4755, Windows 10, a 32-bit operating system, x64-based processor. My processor is Intel® Core™ i3-2330M Processor, and based on the Intel ARK, it is indeed an Intel 64.

The question, will it be safe to upgrade my current Windows 10 32-bit into 64-bit?

Comment: Yes it is......

Answer (score 3):

> that it is possible to upgrade your 32-bit OS to a 64-bit OS IF your
> computer and "hardware" is 64-bit capable.

Is it safe?   Yes, it is completely safe. I have been using 64-bit operating systems since 2008.

You cannot upgrade a 32-bit OS to 64-bit OS in place.

You must back up all your data, and then format and install the 64-bit OS.  Recover both your apps and your data. Use 64-bit Apps wherever you can (Office, Adobe and many others).   Drivers will be 64-bit versions.

Also and separately, make sure Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS to be able to run 64-bit Guest operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe to upgrade to a 64-bit operating system (Linux/Windows/Unix).

But if you have an x86 bit processor, no.

See my own answers to my own questions.

Comment: The upgrade will not install, so there's no "danger".